# Tkinter OptionMenu Title refresh

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm fairly new to the object-oriented world. I just fully grasped just what self is doing today and I'm having issues with the final piece of my code. I have an option box with a list that is being pulled from an array. when an option is selected I need the program to perform a task then set itself back to the title that it was given.

I'm not sure the best way to get around this issue or if it even using the best possible option to make the program is doing.

Here is my code. I have replaced the `clip()` function with `return` so it will need to be changed. in the past, I have just run the `create()` over again to refresh the buttons but that will not work as I can't pass the `master` variable to the `create` function.

```
from tkinter import *

smename = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
smescript = []

class hdtools:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("HDTools")
        master.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.create(master)

    def create(self, master):
        self.add_grid(master, smename, self.index, 'Start, Middle, & End', 1)

    def add_grid(self, master, data, command, title, row):
        var = StringVar(root)
        popupMenu = OptionMenu(master, var, *data, command=command)
        popupMenu.configure(width=20)
        popupMenu.pack()
        var.set(title)

    def index(self, *entry):
        global smename, smescript
        dex = smename.index(*entry)
        self.clip(smescript, dex)

    def clip(self, script, dex):
        return

root = Tk()
gui = hdtools(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to only dynamically change the Tk window title to be the text of the users selection in the drop-down menu? If so, change `return` to `root.title(smename[dex])`

Comment: @davedwards I should have been more clear. the end goal isn't for the optionmenu to display the users text its going to do other things I need it to execute a function like `print(smescript[dex])` then refresh the optionmenu to say start, middle, & end.

Comment: I don't think you understand how `OptionMenu` widgets work—they don't have a title, what they display is the currently selected option or the current value of the associated `stringVar`—but in your code the `var.set(title)` is causing `'Start, Middle, & End'` to be displayed as though it was one of the options which is not one of them. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/optionmenu.html) that might help.

Comment: @TristanRoylancePillowpants thanks for clarifying. If I better understand, and if you have methods for each `smescript[dex]`, then one "hack" might be to instead use `eval()` which executes the string as a function. try `eval('self.'+script[dex]+'()')` . It seemed to do as you described when I used it in your code.